# How do I feed my REST server URL (or other deploy-side variables) into my Angular application?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular. Primarily I'm a server-side developer. I'm building a spring REST server with an Angular front end. I'm don't understand how I can get the URL of the REST server into my Angular app. I can hardcode it, but that doesn't work very well when I deploy.

I presume -- but maybe there's a better way -- that my REST server will also serve up the Angular app with an index.html, and I can produce the latter on the fly. Thus, I could embed whatever I want into the HTML file, but I don't know how I feed that into my component.

Maybe there's a different way to do deploys so that the app knows how to preform its REST calls.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the version, before angular 15 you can just configure the url for different environments in the `environments.ts` file article below

[official docs](https://angular.io/guide/build)

If greater than angular 15, it does not ship with environments by default, so you need to install it using.

```
Ng g environments
```

Relevant article below

[Why no environment.ts](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/angular-15-what-happened-to-environmentts-koh#:%7E:text=Angular%2015%20simply%20doesn%27t,project%20creation%20in%20previous%20versions.)